# PHP Countdown Timer Question, Help much appreciated

Tags: php

So I'm trying to code a php countdown timer that is pure PHP.

The idea is that when something has happened that is saved in the database under the created_at column i want to countdown from that moment 3 weeks.

What i have at the moment is this but this is adding a manual end date.
What i want is that the created_at time gets taken from the database and then 3 weeks added and then counts this down.

```
<?php

    $target = mktime(0, 0, 0, 11, 26, 2021) ; //cant figure this one out

    $today = time () ;

    $difference =($target-$today) ;

    $month =date('m',$difference) ;
    $days =date('d',$difference) ;
    $hours =date('h',$difference) ;

    print $month." month".$days." days".$hours."hours left";

    ?>
```

And so for example:
Today something happens that gets added in the table under the created_at time.
I want to get that created_at time and then countdown to a date 3 weeks in the future.

Comment: @Tiran100 Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts. You have not shown any code on how to read values from the database.

Comment: If im understanding this correctly, then you may want to look into datetime examples on php.net. as a micro optimization i would generate the future date up on creation of the entry, since you don't need to calculate the time every time you load the page then. If you are creating the date automatically via mysql, you can also look into date manipulati9n with mysql. Btw the example you have set doeant work because your mixing date with unix timestamp

Comment: You can calculate the target date quite easily: `$target = date_create("now + 3 weeks");`. Store that and pass it to JavaScript to display a countdown.

Answer (score 0):

Upon re-reading your question, it sounds like your looking to make a timer. PHP will only update the page on page load, so if your timer is counting down, it will refresh every second which isn't ideal. You will want to use something like Javascript for this. You can parse the php datetime to Javascript.

Comment: If you could provide an example of the php -> javascript mapping of the datetime, that would improve your answer.